# Find number of all positive integer triplets $x$, $y$, $z$, if $x(y+1)(z+1) + z = 1009$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Find number of all positive integer triplets $x$, $y$, $z$, if: $$x(y + 1)(z + 1) + z = 1009$$

Comment: Add $1$ & replace $Z=z+1$. Then there are $8$ possible values for $Z$....

Comment: First solution that comes to mind is $x=10$, $y,z=9$

Comment: Do as uncle Donald says and factor 1010.

Comment: I believe $1010=2\cdot 5\cdot 101$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $$x(y+1) = \frac{1010}{z+1}-1=:k$$

with $k$ an integer and $k\geq 2$. So, we get that $$(\underbrace{k+1}_{\geq 3})(\underbrace{z+1}_{\geq 2}) = 1010$$

and from prime factorization $1010 = 2\cdot 5\cdot 101$ we get that the divisors of $1010$ are $$\{1,2,5,10,101,202,505,1010\}$$ and from the above restrictions, we get five cases:

1. $z+1 = 2$, $k+1 = 505$,
2. $z+1 = 5$, $k+1 = 202$,
3. $z+1 = 10$, $k+1 = 101$,
4. $z+1 = 101$, $k+1 = 10$,
5. $z+1 = 202$, $k+1 = 5$.

For each $k$, you can now find number of positive integer solutions of $x(y+1) = k$. Can you finish it from here?